# how to block access to the subfolder and redirect the site of subfolders using .htaccess?

Tags: php, cpanel, octobercms

I have installed **OCTOBERCMS** inside the cpanel public_html and there is also another subfolder called moodle. When I enter a URL like [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) it should open root directory webpage which is octobercms and when I enter the URL [www.example.com/moodle](http://www.example.com/moodle) it should open the pages from moodle subfolder. Now the problem is when I open www.example.com it opens octobercms which is fine but when I open www.example.com/moodle it does not open the moodle page, instead it opens the pages from the octobercms with a "could not find" page. So, now I want to block access of octobercms from the moodle subfolder and having the moodle index.php  open when [www.example.com/moodle](http://www.example.com/moodle) URL is entered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `/moodle` to october's `.htaccess`

```
## White listed folders
# OMMITED
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/moodle/.*
RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: i have already tried this but did not worked it still shows tha pages from octobercms in moodle url.

Comment: @swastikshrestha did you try adding  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/moddle` to the `Block PHP files` too?